# Web analytics solution for website creator

Tags: api, google-analytics, web-analytics, matomo

I have site which is a creator of smaller websites,
and I'd like to have separate analytics for each user.

Is there a way do automate adding the Google Analytics to the website?

As far as I can see, there's no such options in Google API.

Any other alternatives? Can this be done with Piwik?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Piwik, you can use the Analytics API: http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/ to create websites automatically, then fetch the javascript code automatically and add it into your websites. You can then create a user automatically with access to this website and your users will be able to login and enjoy their websites stats in the Piwik UI. You will need to call the API a few times and will need a bit of development knowledge (at least know how to call REST API etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Read [This Article](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples) which discusses Page-level Custom Variables.  Scroll down to the example of the different sections of a newspaper.  In your case you would use a custom variable which would uniquely identify the "sub-site".

Some promotional content.  Sounds like you are developing a Content Management System (CMS) and want to offer the sub-site owners a "Analytics" page.  If this is the case check out [embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) (Disclaimer: I work with them).  This is a site which enables you to embed google analytic charts into your site without getting into the nuts and bolts of the API.  While it is not yet published on our site, we also have many ways to support CMS type systems described above.  Visit us and if you are interested in how it can be absorbed into a CMS drop us a message.

Answer (score 0):

Infunl (Disclaimer: I am a co-founder), which is currently in private beta, will provide API with flexibility to provide foundation for per-micro-site live analytics dashboards. This can be done with [backend attributes](https://infunl.com/#split), [grouping](https://infunl.com/#group) or [group by segmentation](https://infunl.com/#groupby). I would love to hear if this could solve your problem.